# Multi-index table/row search

Tags: javascript

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp

I'm using the JavaScript from this W3 schools page, and it gives a tip on how to change the single index you want to search through, but what if I want to loop through/search multiple indexes of the row at once?

For example I want to search through both index 0 and 1 at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the code from this website https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp

I modified the code like you wanted, you can research by Name and country at the same time, here the javascript code:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    td2 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td2 || td) {
      if (td2.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 || td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1)      {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    } 
  }
}
</script>
```

I hope this is what you wanted

Comment: Perfect answer thank you!!! Do you know of a more efficient way to do it if lets say you have 10 indexes?